# Selenium WebDriver - If element present select it, if not ignore it and continue to next element

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am just finishing a test script and accessing a fairly dynamic page. The page in question, has an element appear (generally a radio button or tick-box), which is only present if certain criteria in previous pages are met. So, my test will be accessing this page irrelevant of previous criteria and I want to hit the "continue" element at the bottom of the page whilst handling these elements "IF" they appear. I have a few method sto click elements by ID, and so far have the following code:

```
 // Selects the "Confirm" button
                IWebElement radioOption = mWebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("Radio_Button_Id"));
                if (radioOption.Displayed)
                {
                    this.ClickElementById("Radio_Button_Id");

                    // Clicks CONTINUE
                    this.ClickElementById("CONTINUE");
                }
                else
                {
                    // Selects CONTINUE
                    this.ClickElementById("CONTINUE");
                }
```

I am trying in this code to handle that if the radio button appears, select it then select the continue button. Also, if the radio button does not appear, ignore it and select the continue button. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Great, you've explained what you are trying to do, what you are doing at the moment, but you've not explained why this doesn't work at the moment? What does this code do? What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: Im new to this, as you were at one stage. At the moment I have set up a "No Such Element" exception which is being returned, linked to the "Radio_Button_Id". This flags at the start of the code snippet if the element is not present. I am expecting the code to look for the the element, if not present then ignore it and if it is present then catch it and select it > then select "Continue".

Comment: you are thinking in the right direction... try to implement it :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
//Displayed
public static bool IsElementDisplayed(this IWebDriver driver, By element)
{
    IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(element);
    if (elements.Count > 0)
    {
        return elements.ElementAt(0).Displayed;
    }
    return false;
}

//Enabled
public static bool IsElementEnabled(this IWebDriver driver, By element)
{
    IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(element);
    if (elements.Count > 0)
    {
        return elements.ElementAt(0).Enabled;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You'll not get any exception and then the test can continue.

Comment: Adapted the above structure to fit in with my methods and created a new method enclosing this structure for future refrence (if I encounter the same events elsewhere). Works a treat!

Comment: I know this is old but I just ran across it and there's a few simple things you can do to reduce the amount of code and make it more efficient so I updated the answer. It still works the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You said that you were getting NoSuchElementExceptions. `radioOption.Displayed` tests to see if the element is visible on the page, but it will throw an error if the element doesn't even exist.  (An element can be present, but invisible)

To test to see if an element is present, you need to do `mWebDriver.FindElements` (note the S).  This will return a `List<WebElement>` of all of the elements that match your selector, and if it can't find any, it will return a list of size 0 (and not throw an error).

That way, your if statement will be `if (radioOptions.size()!=0)`, and will check to see if the element exists (not if its visible).

Answer (score 0):

I've also used this as a way to test if the element is present and get a handle on the element if it is present:

```
namespace SeleniumExtensions
{
    public static class WebDriverExtensions
    {
        public static bool TryFindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, out IWebElement element)
        {
            try
            {
                element = driver.FindElement(by);

                return true;
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException)
            {
                element = null;

                return false;
            }
        }

        public static bool IsElementEnabled(this IWebDriver driver, By by)
        {
            IWebElement element = null;

            if (driver.TryFindElement(by, out element))
            {
                return element.Enabled;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This allows for code like:

```
using SeleniumExtensions;

// ...

IWebElement element = null;

if (driver.TryFindElement(By.Id("item-01"), out element)
{
    // use element
}
else
{
     // element is null
}
```

Or:

```
if (driver.IsElementEnabled(By.Id("item-01"))
{
    // item is enabled
}
```